# android broadcast receiver sending null pointer exception

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am facing Null Pointer Exception in this class..

The code works perfect for first time but after 2nd or 3rd time it gives me error...

Please help me to solve my problem

```
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() != null
                    && intent.getAction().equals(MyActions.CONTACT_LIST_UPDATE)) {
            /*   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contact Updated",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                mFavList.clear();
                if (!dbAdapter.isOpen()) {
                    dbAdapter.openForRead();
                }

                mFavList.addAll(dbAdapter.getAllUsers());
                mFavoriteListAdapter = new FavoriteListAdapter(
                        LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), mFavList, getActivity());
                lstchat.setAdapter(mFavoriteListAdapter);
                // dbAdapter.close();
                mFavoriteListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (mFavList.size() == 0) {
                //  llLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //  tvLoadingMessage.setText("No Contacts");
                //  pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    //llLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                pastChatList.clear();

                pastChatList.addAll(dbAdapter.getPastChats());
                if (!dbAdapter.isOpen()) {
                    dbAdapter.openForRead();
                }
                dbAdapter.addAllGroups(pastChatList);

                dbAdapter.close();
                mPastChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    }
```

LogCat

```
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at com.addonwebsolution.yarg.activity.ChatFragment$MyReceiver.onReceive(ChatFragment.java:134)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-31 12:58:00.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the error getting on

```
mFavoriteListAdapter = new FavoriteListAdapter(
                    LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), mFavList, getActivity());
```

Comment: Use `context` instead of `getActivity()`. Your `Context` is null.

Comment: i am using fragment so i write getActivity()

Comment: But in `onRecieve()` method it has its own `Context`. So give a try to it. Also check u have initialized your `mFavList`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's started from in-background. At this time, getActivity() in null, you should use "**context**" parameter of onReceive method.